# Intel Compute Stick & USB 4G Device

Tags: computer-architecture, intel, cellular

Id like to create a powerful IoT Edge device that has cellular capability (Wifi is undesirable). Right now the intel compute stick/neural stick almost fits the bill except that it does not have 4G capability.

So what id like to do is buy a compute stick and an USB 4G modem device and connect them via USB link.

I want to explore if it is possible to fuse the underlying circuits together of both of them (Compute stick + USB 4G modem device) and make a professional looking monolith out of it.

The idea is that the monolith comes with power of intel compute stick plus a 4G capability! at the same time not bulking out too much and/or becoming heavy.

Is this possible to accomplish that in the capacity of individual developer?

More importantly will it violate usage policy of the individual component manufacturers? (Intel or 4G modem manufacturer?)

If this is not a viable solution, is there an industry out of the box lightweight alternative computing platform that comes with 4G capability built into it?

Comment: @Toor Thanks for the answer, yes I am fairly aware of that. But that is only half the picture. The other half is the computing device itself (either neural sticks running AI compiled algorithms - or a plain vanilla miniature computing stick (running super light weight linux alpine core with a super light mobile GUI for administration)

Comment: I had deleted my previous comment because I re-read your question and realized what you were actually asking about before your page updated.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking about here -- the [Intel Compute Stick](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/boards-kits/compute-stick.html) and [Intel Neural Compute Stick](https://software.intel.com/en-us/movidius-ncs) are (confusingly) two _completely_ different products. Either way, though, this looks like a question about using electronic devices, not about designing them; it might be more appropriate on [Super User](//superuser.com).

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to compete against what I do for my company (but we're doing 5G and 4G solutions) **;)** Yes, you could do it by yourself. I am using OpenVINO to run some demos for our edge computing products.

Comment: @duskwuff It doesn’t matter if you consider intel compute stick or neural stick. My issue is more about integration and packaging than the platform. I just happened to take neural stick as an example.

Comment: If you can get a moderately normal Linux on the compute half in order to run typical software, and it can be a USB host, and you can power the mobile data modem, then this should be fairly workable **as a combination of modules**.   But no, re-spinnning the component boards is not within your capability.  At best you might be able to do a board carrying two permanently soldered sub-modules, but really you should satisfy yourself that a connectorized solution meets your need before investing in that, either with off the shelf items and a USB cable, or with mPCIe or whatever connectors.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thanks for that answer. Makes lot of sense. I agree it is beyond individual capacity to fuse the circuits. Just wondering if modular combination as you mentioned is a normal value added reselling practice? Also curious to know if end user agreements prevent this?

Comment: @KingDuken Thanks for the response. It just gets to show how cheap plain ideas are ;)If something makes sense - thousands would’ve thought about it already!  Magic is in execution.